How to get focus on checkboxes in inovua ReactDataGrid?
If you set rows in a ReactDataGrid from inovua to be selectable (enableSelection={true}) , you get what look like checkboxes, but they are in fact divs with svg images inside. They therefore are not on the path of the focus when you use the Shift key. How can I set them to be focussable?
Here is what the HTML for the checkbox looks like:
<div 
    class="inovua-react-toolkit-checkbox 
           InovuaReactDataGrid__checkbox 
           inovua-react-toolkit-checkbox--children-position-end 
           inovua-react-toolkit-checkbox--ltr 
           inovua-react-toolkit-checkbox--inline-block 
           inovua-react-toolkit-checkbox--unchecked 
           inovua-react-toolkit-checkbox--theme-default-light">
           <div class="inovua-react-toolkit-checkbox__icon-wrapper">
              <svg width="16" height="16" class="" style="height: 16px; width: 16px;" viewBox="0 0 16 16"><rect width="14" height="14" x="1" y="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd" stroke-width="2" rx="1"></rect>
              </svg>
          </div>
      </div>


reactdatagrid.io appears to have no current valid DNS entries; maybe the owner simply gave up on the domain name. But I am guessing that https://github.com/adazzle/react-data-grid/blob/main/README.md is the same thing?

@C3roe I think they are 2 different components from different editors (adazzle vs inovua). The ReactDataGrid I am using has no hyphens in their name, and the tag is , not  as indicated in the linked page.

@jonrsharpe I saw you edited this question, to remove the related question of where the relevant documentation can be found... Do you have any suggestions about what to do about the website of a module disappearing in thin air? If you don't, why squash the thin hope that someone on StackOverflow would have some idea?
